# Simple Assignment

Tags: c, bit-shift

Here's my problem. I have the following structure defined

```
struct idt_reg{
  unsigned short limit;
  unsigned int base;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

In my code I do the following assignment

```
unsigned short num_ids = idtr.limit >> 3;
```

Now upon execution, when the value stored in `idtr.limit` is equal to 2047(0x7FF), what I expected to happen was a right shift of 3 bits (divide by 8) and get the value of 255 written to num_ids. Instead the value of `num_ids` is always 0.

Any help I would really appreciate.

Comment: "what I expected to happen was a right shift of 3 bytes (divide  by 8)" Nope, a right shift of 3 __bits__.

Comment: If right-shifted by 3, it would be 255 (0xFF).  ;)

Comment: So could you show a more complete snippet.  How you set `idtr`, how you determine that `num_ids` is `0`.  Did you print it?  See it in a debugger? etc.

Comment: Expanding the missing parts, it works here as expected (255 and not 256).

Comment: Have you printed out the value of idtr.limit and are sure it has the value 2047 , or are you just assuming it should have the value 2047 ?

Comment: I am supremely sorry guys. I seem to have made that shift before assigning a value to idtr.limit. My utmost apologies to you all. It's a terrible lack of concentration on my part. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct idt_reg{
  unsigned short limit;
  unsigned int base;
}__attribute__((packed));

int main() {
    struct idt_reg idtr;
    unsigned short num_ids;
    idtr.limit = 2047;
    num_ids = idtr.limit >> 3;
    printf( "%d\n", num_ids );
}
```

prints 255.